# Array of Photos from Assets Cassets displayed in CollectionViewCells

Tags: swift

I am having some trouble displaying images from the assetsCassets into my collectionViewCells.

I have 4 images named "Avenues", "Streets", "Hotels", "Restaurants"

**My code for instantiating the array with the images is the following:**

```
var arrayFotos = ["Avenues", "Streets", "Hotels", "Restaurants"]
```

**And then to display it on the collectionViewCell, I do the following code:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CVCellFotos", for: indexPath) as! FotosCollectionViewCell
        
        for image in arrayFotos {
            cell.imgFoto.image = UIImage(named: image)
            }
        return cell
    }
```

**However, it is only returning one of my four images. How could I display the four images into my collectionViewCell??**

Answer (score 0):

I presume that it is only displaying the "Restaurants" image. This is because you are running a for loop, resetting the image to be displayed by `cell.imgFoto`, starting first with "Avenues" and then ending with "Restaurants".

To fix this, it depends what are you trying to accomplish. Are you trying to display all four images in one cell? Or have four different cells, each with one image?

If you want the former, then you need to create four different image views in your cell, and then you can set them like this in the `cellForItemAt` method:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CVCellFotos", for: indexPath) as! FotosCollectionViewCell       

cell.imgFoto1.image = UIImage(named: arrayFotos[0])
cell.imgFoto2.image = UIImage(named: arrayFotos[1])
cell.imgFoto3.image = UIImage(named: arrayFotos[2])
cell.imgFoto4.image = UIImage(named: arrayFotos[3])

return cell
```

If you want the latter, then you need to return `4` cells or `arrayFotos.count` (assuming you have only one section) in the `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int` method.

Then, you can do the following in the `cellForItemAt` method:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CVCellFotos", for: indexPath) as! FotosCollectionViewCell      
  
cell.imgFoto.image = UIImage(named: arrayFotos[indexPath.row])

return cell
```

This will create four different cells, each has its own image view set by the data in arrayFoto depending on the indexPath.row.